# Numpy array splitting based on data type?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following array:

```
arr = [ nan nan nan 1.600e-01 1.000e+00 1.600e-01 9.999e-01 1.000e-04 1.600e-01 1.010e-01 nan 1.600e-01]
```

How I can obtain the following lists?

```
listA = [nan nan nan] #values in position 0, 1, 2
listB = [1.600e-01 1.000e+00 1.600e-01 9.999e-01 1.000e-04 1.600e-01 1.010e-01] #values in position 3 to 9
listC = [nan] #the values in position 10
listD = [1.600e-01] # the values in position 11
```

Thank you

Comment: listA has 2 items, but in comment you said there were 3 values. Is it a typo?

Comment: it's a trouble, here the correct output:

Comment: listA = [nan nan nan] #values in position 0, 1, 2
listB = [1.600e-01 1.000e+00 1.600e-01 9.999e-01 1.000e-04 1.600e-01 1.010e-01] #values in position 3 to 9
listC = [nan] #the values in position 10
listD = [1.600e-01] # the values in position 11

Comment: listA = arr[:3]

Answer (score 3):

use numpy `split` to split array based on a condition. the condition is defined  whenever `np.diff(np.isnan(arr))`== `True`

```
np.split(arr, np.where(np.diff(np.isnan(arr))== True)[0]+1)

[array([nan, nan, nan]),
 array([1.600e-01, 1.000e+00, 1.600e-01, 9.999e-01, 1.000e-04, 1.600e-01,
        1.010e-01]),
 array([nan]),
 array([0.16])]
```